# ReactJS - Undefined Element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have this component below and there is an error caused by the `changeColor()` function which results an error message:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined

It is the only error in the component. All the other things are working successfully. The JSON data is fetched good and the component renderization is fine too. Of course it was before I have implemented the function `changeColor()` which blocked the app.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

var data = require('./db.json');

class Cronology extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            cronology: [],
            year: "",
            description: ""
        }

        this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.setState({
            cronology: data.cronology
        })

        this.changeColor();
    }

    changeColor() {
        document.querySelectorAll('p').style.color = 'red'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                {
                    this.state.cronology && this.state.cronology.map(
                        (i) => {
                            return (
                                <tr>
                                    <th className="column1">• {i.year}</th>
                                    <th className="column2"><p>{i.description}</p></th>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
            </table>
        )
    }
}
export default Cronology;
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('p')`  will return array like structure,
you may use 

`document.querySelectorAll('p')[0].style.color = 'red'`

to change color of first p elements color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a supplement for others' answers, you can use `forEach`, that is:
 `document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(el => el.style.color = 'red');`

Answer (score 4):

Your `changeColor()` method is using `document.querySelectorAll('p')` which returns a collection. You have to target the specific  element.

`document.querySelectorAll('p')[0].style.color = "red"` for example

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll